# Refactor two jQuery filter functions into one function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two separate lists both sitting side by side. How can I refactor the code below to only have one filter function for both lists?

```
$("input.filterInput").keyup(function() {
    filter(this); 
});

function filter(element) {
    var value = $(element).val();
    $(".pdfList > li").each(function (){
        if ($(this).text().indexOf(value) > -1) {
                $(this).show();
        } else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
}

$("input.filterInput2").keyup(function() {
    filter2(this); 
});

function filter2(element) {
    var value = $(element).val();
    $(".pdfList2 > li").each(function (){
        if ($(this).text().indexOf(value) > -1) {
                $(this).show();
        } else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have the following two inputs in your HTML.

```
<input id="filterInput1" />
<input id="filterInput2" />
```

Then you can wire them both up together, or split it into separate assignments:

```
$('#filterInput1, #filterInput2').each(function () {
    $(this).keyup(function () {
        filter(this);
    });
});
```

Finally, check the ID of the element that triggered the function call to see what list you should be trying to highlight:

```
function filter(element) {
    var value = $(element).val(),
        selector;

    if (element.id === 'filterInput1') {
        selector = '.pdfList';
    } else if (element.id === 'filterInput2') {
        selector = '.pdfList2';
    } else {
        return; // Or throw an error, whatever you feel is more appropriate.
    }

    // Now the dropdown selector is stored in the variable, and will change which
    // it is looking at depending on who called it.
    $(selector + " > li").each(function (){
        if ($(this).text().indexOf(value) > -1) {
                $(this).show();
        } else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried that. It filters both independent lists at the same time...

Comment: Yeah, I just went back and took another look and realized. Give me a minute.

Comment: There ya go. Additional checks can (and probably should) be done to make sure that the element has the `filterInput2` class, but that's added easily enough.

Comment: would i keep each input tag as having its own class? or would .filterInput be assigned to both input tags?

Comment: If you're using the classes to set up CSS, then I would. Since this is Code Review, the best place to denote the difference between the two elements would probably be in a `data-xxxxx` attribute to follow with the recommended convention.

Comment: im just using them to distinguish between input fields. I should probably make them ids

Comment: So i am going to have two different functions to call the filter function correct?

Comment: Selector is being set in the if/else if/else sequence after the variable declaration. If you don't find either of those two ids, then either bail from the function, or throw an error.

Comment: for some reason the keyup function is not firing...